# Route to get a member of a model by a value other than :id

Tags: rest, ruby-on-rails-4, collections, routes, members

I have `Students`, each of which has a standard `:id` but they also have a `:student_number` which is unique. I would like to be able to find a view a student given only their `:student_number`

Here's the route I have now:

```
resources :students do    
    collection do
        get 'find_by_num'
    end
end
```

This works, but it feels a little strange, creating a 'collection' for what I know will be a single result--that is, a 'member'. At the same time, members expect `:id` and I don't have one.

What would be the accepted, RESTful way of doing this?

I searched for an existing answer and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494096/how-do-you-get-a-restful-resource-by-something-other-than-id) question, but I'm interested in the route itself.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I hope I understood correctly your question and you want something like

`http://myapp.com/users/student_number` to get you to the specific student.

If that is the case, you don't need to do anything with the routing, just in the Users Controller

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by(student_number: params[:id])
end
```

Then in your views, to link to the student you will have:

```
= link_to user.name, user_path(user.student_number)
```

Comment: That's a nice clean solution, but unfortunately, I have to keep `show` working with `:id`, which is a different column than `:student_number`

The student numbers are "unique" in this particular case, but not in all cases because...I don't know. Universities have really strange database structures.